# ZXing widget in ios scans only 1 time

Tags: ios, zxing, qr-code

I am using Zxing Widget is my iOS project to scan QR code. I know that in iOS 7 you can use integrated QR code reader, but I need to support iOS 6 users, so I use Zxing.

**Problem:**

The problem is that I can't make it work the way I need. I need to do continuous scanning, so the user could scan several codes in sequence without closing the window with scanner.

But in my case, after first scanning the scanner does not respond to qr codes. I can still see the signal from camera, but the codes aren't scanned.

Here's my code for initializing:

```
self.widController =[[ZXingWidgetController alloc] initWithDelegate:self showCancel:YES OneDMode:NO];

NSMutableSet *readers = [[NSMutableSet alloc ] init];
MultiFormatReader* reader = [[MultiFormatReader alloc] init];
[readers addObject:reader];
self.widController.readers = readers;

AppDelegate *delegate=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
CGRect wholeWindow=delegate.window.bounds;
[self.widController.view setFrame:wholeWindow];

[delegate.window addSubview:self.widController.view];
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you considered how small the number of iOS 6 users are that download much less buy apps?